# Enable link to be clicked at least twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing a like functionality and here is the challenge I am having.

Once the user clicks on like, the js below runs and renders a string from the server, which is a partial view. Then I have unlike link/icon there to enable user to unlike it. But I cant click on it, ie; the link is dead, doesnt fire. DEAD.

```
$('.like-button').click(function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    var projectid = btn.attr('id').replace('like_', '');

    $.post('/Projects/Like', {
        projectid: projectid
    }).done(function(data) {

        if (data.likePart) {
            $('#likepart_' + projectid).html(data.likePart);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

EDIT:

This is the html:

`{"likePart":"\u003cspan class=\"badge bg-aqua\" id=\"count_10\"\u003e\r\n    0\r\n\u003c/span\u003e\r
\n\r\n    \u003ca href=\"#\" id=\"like_10\" class=\"like-button\"\u003e\r\n        \u003ci class=\"fa
 fa-heart-o\" style=\"color: #ff0000;\"\u003e\u003c/i\u003e\r\n    \u003c/a\u003e\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n
    \u003cspan\u003e İlk beğenen siz olun.\u003c/span\u003e\r\n"}`

How can I ensure that once the link returns, user can click on it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the HTML. It seems you are replacing HTML

Comment: If you want a system like or dislike, view this tutorial: http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-create-like-unlike-system-in-php-mysql-and-jquery_410.html

Comment: Also, show the HTML that is returned

Comment: It looks like when you replace the originally clicked link, you aren't attaching a listener. Select what you just replaced the button with and attach another listener to it.

Also, consider making your code more modular by writing a `toggle` function. Then you can call it whenever anything gets clicked.

Comment: Your HTML formatting is broken

Comment: how is it broken? it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `on`:

```
$(document/parentSelector).on('click', '.like-button', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: Don't guess, Let OP post his HTML

Comment: I was thinking same, but this will not work if the returned HTML does not contain the like-button class

Comment: `Then I have unlike link/icon there to enable user to unlike it. But I cant click on it, ie; the link is dead, doesnt fire. DEAD.`

Comment: Its still a good guess might be correct. Just hold till OP add HTML

Comment: @DarthVader  learn [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) `$(document).on('click', '.like-button', function () { `